# Checking data vectors in SAS

Tags: sas

I want to simply check the values read in SAS.  In the raw data file

```
----+---10----+---20
H Let
P Grn Lea Qua Gro
P Ice     Pls Frm
P Rom     Qua Gro
H Sqs
P Ylw     Tas Acr
P Zuc     Pls Frm
```

I submitted a code

```
data a;
infile 'FileA.txt';
 retain vege;
 input code $1. @;
  if code='H' then input @3 vege $3.;
  if code='P';
   input @3 variety : $10. @15 Supplier : $11.;
run;
proc print noobs;
run;
```

I got the observations

```
Let P Gm  Gro
Let P Ice Frm
Let P Rom Gro
Sqs P Ylw Acr
Sqs P Zuc Frm
```

I uderstand that the if code=P; is the reason why the code value is P, but I would like to know if there was supposed to be more observations.

According to the text book I am working on, the sixth observations has certain values and it is indicated by _ N _ =6.

I am still learning and not quite sure what it means... may I have some help?

Thank you.

Comment: if code='P'; logic details in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53276299/using-first-variable-and-last-variables-with-accumulator-variables/53306982#53306982

Comment: Looks like something has changed `Grn` to `Gm` in the first output row. Probably just a transcription error.

Answer (score 1):

An `if` without a `then` is a special form of `if` not found in other languages.  It is known as a subsetting `if` and program flow only passes through the statement when the evaluation if true.

Data set rows are `output` tacitly and implicitly when program flow reaches the bottom of the step (unless there is an explicit `output` elsewhere in the step)

Thus, all the data file lines were read, only five of them met the sub-setting if criteria asserted by `if code='P';` and fell through to the end of the step and were implicitly output.